# The mean of a dataframe of NaN's is Zero, instead of NaN

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a dataframe of various timeseries, where the data starts at various points in time. So to have the same starting point, they are all padded with `NaN`, like so:

```
location    townA   townB
datanumber   1234    1235
1940-01-01    NaN     NaN  
1940-02-01    NaN     NaN  
1940-03-01    NaN     NaN  
1940-04-01    NaN     NaN  
1940-05-01   0.53     NaN
```

I need to get the average for all my locations, so it seems like `meandf = locdf.mean(axis = 1)` should do the job. The [documentation for `pd.mean()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html?highlight=mean#pandas.DataFrame.mean) tells me that

> skipna : boolean, default True
>
> Exclude NA/null values. If an entire row/column is NA, the result will be NA

it does skip NA values (which is the same as NaN?), just as all other functions in pandas do, so I would expect a result like

```
1940-01-01    NaN
1940-02-01    NaN
1940-03-01    NaN
1940-04-01    NaN
1940-05-01    0.53
```

but I get

```
1940-01-01    0
1940-02-01    0
1940-03-01    0
1940-04-01    0
1940-05-01    0.53
```

which wreaks havoc afterwards, because everything else in pandas seems to work well with `NaN`, hence I am always using it.

Specifying it again just to be sure with `skipna = 'True'` produces the same result, and also `numeric_only` does not change anything.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What pandas version are you using? this works as described in version `0.17.0`

Comment: I'm on `0.14.1`. Could have sworn I updated only a few weeks ago. But still, the [0.14.1 documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.14.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html?highlight=mean#pandas.DataFrame.mean) says the same. If I do a `df.head()` and I get the above output, that should really mean that this is my dataframe, right? So there cant be any hidden zeros?

Comment: But apart from my answer that explains the 'why', I have to agree that the docs should be updated!

Comment: Actually, I misread your question, and my answer only holds for `sum`, not for `mean`. I actually see the correct behaviour (giving NaN for mean) on both 0.14.1 as latest 0.17.0. Can you show your installed versions (pandas, numpy, bottleneck)?

Comment: pandas is `0.14.1` and numpy is on `1.9.2`, whereas bottleneck does not seem to be installed. `import bottleneck` just results in `ImportError: No module named bottleneck`.

Comment: I have an environment with exactly the same versions (for those three), but do not see the issue. Can you post a reproducible example? (some code to make up a small dataframe that shows the strange behaviour for you)

Answer (score 4):

This is a known confusing issue with pandas/numpy. In short, the actual outcome of the operation will depend on the version of `bottleneck` that you have installed, as pandas defers to bottleneck for these calculations. See also https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9422 (and [GH11409](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11409))

`bottleneck`changed its implementation of `nansum` to return 0 on all NaN arrays instead of NaN. This was to match the behaviour of numpy's `nansum`. For this reason, the actual behaviour in pandas can be inconsistent depending on if and which version of bottleneck is installed.

---

The numpy behaviour:

```
In [2]: a = np.array([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan])

In [3]: a
Out[3]: array([ nan,  nan,  nan])

In [4]: np.nansum(a)
Out[4]: 0.0
```

The logic is that the sum of nothing is 0 (you get nothing as you skip all NaNs here).

By default, pandas deviates from this behaviour and *does* return NaN (the result you expected):

```
In [6]: s = pd.Series(a)

In [7]: s.sum()
Out[7]: nan
```

When you have bottleneck installed, this will be used for this calculation. Previously, bottleneck also returned NaN, so you would get a consistent behaviour whether you have bottleneck installed or not. However, a more recent version of bottleneck changed the behaviour (>= 1.0) to match the behaviour of numpy's `nansum`.
So if you have this version of bottleneck installed, you will see another behaviour:

```
In [1]: a = np.array([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan])

In [2]: np.nansum(a)
Out[2]: 0.0

In [3]: s = pd.Series(a)

In [4]: s.sum()
Out[4]: 0.0

In [5]: import bottleneck

In [6]: bottleneck.__version__
Out[6]: '1.0.0'
```

I think there is something to say for both results (0 or NaN), and there is not one of both that is 'wrong', but of course what is most confusing/problematic is that the behaviour differs between pandas and numpy/bottleneck.